# One Locale translation folder - Several server instances

Tags: python, django, locale

I am setting up a new server infrastructure and plan to have multiple app-servers running django. One thing I am wondering about is how to handle the Locale folder.

As it is now, I use django-rosetta (which is an awesome app btw) to handle the translations on the production server. That works fine because I have only one app-server running. When I migrate to a setup with multiple servers I´d like to avoid having to enter every server instance and make the same changes.

I do not have my language files checked into the repo and like to keep it that way. Not a fan of merging those at all...

Ideas that crossed my mind is having a script that transfers the translated folder to the other instances once the changes are made on server_1. Could also maybe do some kind of folder sharing over the network I guess.

What would y´all say is the best solution for this?

Comment: We ended up aiming for a rsync solution and then restarting the servers.